# How to create patches for all changes to a file in a branch

Tags: mercurial, patch

A number of changes have been made to a file in a branch. Some of the changes were for a feature that now needs to be implemented on the main branch.

How can I create a patch for each revision of the file so that I can choose which changes I wish to apply to my main branch? Ideally I would like each patch to contain the description of the revision too for reference purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a log for just one file by quoting that file in the log command:

```
hg log FILENAME
```

and you can get the diff for a certain revision and filename by giving both as argument to log, asking it to give you the patch (I've configured my hg to use the git-style patch format by default - maybe that's needed here, too):

```
hg log --patch --rev XXX FILENAME
```

if you want a patch for each revision FILENAME was changed, you could try in bash something like

```
for rev in $(hg log -T"{rev}\n" FILENAME); do hg log -p -r${rev} FILENAME > FILENAME.${rev}.patch; done
```

which yields you the typical patches, including the commit message used:

```
$ cat FILENAME.15.patch 
Änderung:        15:441bead3e0b3
Vorgänger:       7:36479da8f266
Nutzer:          planetmaker <email@example.org>
Datum:           Tue Feb 10 22:58:24 2015 +0100
Zusammenfassung: More boo

diff --git a/FILENAME b/FILENAME
--- a/FILENAME
+++ b/FILENAME
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 foo is boo!
+Even moar booo!
```